# Order MySQL Results by letter and number (A1, B2, B3, C2)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How could I go about ordering the results of a MySQL table by letter and number?

Example, order A3, N8, C3, Z2, U1 as A3, C3, U1, Z2. This could be done within the query or with PHP afterhand.

EDIT: Need to order U23 before U100.

Comment: zerkms's answer looks good, unless you want some special ordering that isn't described by your example data.

Comment: Are the letter and the number in the same field?  Or different fields?  And are they the only thing in the field(s)?  And are all the numbers the same number of digits?

Comment: ORDER BY is the answer but you may be asking the wrong question.  check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399591/sql-sort-order-by-the-order-specified-in-the-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible is to break into two field for sorting, like

```
order by substring(cols,1,1), lpad(substring(cols,2),10,0)
                        ^ assuming only prefix single char 
                              ^ lpad like 0000000001
```

Comment: Instead of using lpad, you could also use ABS()

Answer (score 4):

```
ORDER BY my_field
```

will do the work. `ORDER BY` sorts numbers, strings, dates, etc in natural way.

```
ORDER BY LEFT(fld, 1),
         CAST(SUBSTRING(fld, 1) AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make it order by the letter then the number.

Comment: @Charles Zink: when you sort strings - then A2 follows A1, because first chars are the same, and second are compared. Do you have only one-digit numbers like "N9" or you have multi-digits ones like "O42" and want "O42" to be before "O100"?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @Charles Zink: changed my answer. Also I would suggest you to store the parts separately: char and number.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but may be the most easiest to maintain if you don't have too many cases.

```
ORDER BY CASE id
           ...
           WHEN 'U23' THEN 1
           WHEN 'U100' THEN 2
           ...
         END
```